# Pass a function to a JavaScript class using struct annotation

Tags: javascript, function, class, variables

Hi I need to create a class which can set properties as a function in JS, something like this:

```
var myClass = {

    myFunction: null,

    otherFunction : function ()
    {
        myFunction();
    }
}

function initPage()
{
    myClass.myFunction = function() { ... }
}
```

When i want use use myFunction, i can write: `myClass.otherFunction();`

Is it possible?

Comment: Why dont you call `myFunction` directly?

Comment: It is possible, but you need `this.myfunction()` in `otherFunction` body. http://jsfiddle.net/GhmUm/

Comment: I need to create a class that can be used for multiple purposes

Comment: `myClass` from your code in the context of JavaScript would be considered a *namespace*, not a *class*, as you don't create any instances of it, but keep some methods/properties there instead of creating global variables.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `this` to get to `myFunction` (which is after all, a property of the object):

```
otherFunction : function ()
{
    this.myFunction();
}
```

What you have in the code in your question will look for `myFunction` in the closest available scope. The last thing it would look for is `window.myFunction`. As it is, it would probably error out (because there is no `myFunction`.

Again, the difference is that `myFunction` will look for scoped variables, whereas `this.myFunction` will look at properties of `this`, just like `myClass.myFunction` will look at properties of `myClass` (where `myClass` itself is a scoped variable).

Comment: Yes sorry I was wrong to write the post, anyway when I use the function I get this error: **Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'myFunction' ** I think i can't include customs function in a class value

Answer (score 0):

If you call it as `this.myFunction()` it would work. But what's the benefit? What are you trying to achieve?

If you want to define a myClass as something to be instantiable, you have to define it like this:

```
var myClass = function(){

    myFunction: null;

    someFunction: function(){...};

    otherFunction : function ()
    {
        this.myFunction();
    }
}
```

Then instantiate it like a normal JavaScript object:

```
var myClassInstance = new myClass();
```

and call its methods:

```
myClassInstance.someFunction();
```

in this way, if you want to add a new method to your class declaration dynamically, you can use `prototype` property of your class. It's a reference to your class definition that let you alter your class definition dynamically.

```
myClass.prototype.myFunction = function() { ... };
```

and then call myFunction directly.

```
myClassInstance.myFunction();
```

For more information about using prototype concept, take a look at this resource:

[Inheritance and The Prototype Chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)